# pandas merge same name columns group by

Tags: python, pandas

i have the following frame:

```
col1 col1 

null  hi
hello null
```

I am trying to merge the two columns as they have the same name:

```
col1
hi
hello
```

I am using:

```
result= result.groupby(result.columns, axis=1).first()
```

But the first() applies it to the whole column so i get:

```
col1
hi
null
```

Anyone to merge the columns and avoid the null values.

Comment: Do you have only 2 columns? Do you have only one value in each row, while the others are null?

Comment: Your solution working nice with your sample data, `null` are always `NaN`s or `None`s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution working nice if `null` are converted to `NaN`s.

So maybe problem is `null` are sometimes `string`s, so first `replace`.

```
df = df.replace('null', np.nan).groupby(df.columns, axis=1).first()
print (df)
    col1
0     hi
1  hello
```